# Django VariableDoesNotExist, Failed lookup for ket [currency]

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am facing to this problem with my django application on production dream-access.com
I have 500 for this issue below:
VariableDoesNotExist at /fr/
Failed lookup for key [currency] in <django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x7f31c7411ba8>

can somebody hekp to fix this error ?
Please.
Thanks.

Comment: show your code. what you have done.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I have resolved the problem since yesterday by doing this    
      if not request.session.has_key('currency'):
           request.session['currency'] = settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY